# 5 Ghz Hostapd device for RPI

Tags: usb, wifi

I am looking for a hostapd compatible usb dongle that I can use on the Pi in Infrastructure/master mode. The Important part is, that the Infrastructure/master mode should be able to work in the 5ghz range.

I tried to get devices form [this site,](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices/USB) but I couldn't find one capable of 5ghz Infrastructure/master mode.

Answer (score 1):

i read that this one works on a Synology DSM 4.2 (DS209+II) and under 4.3 Beta (DS411+II) as a 5ghz access point with hostapd:

[TRENDnet 300 Mbps Dual Band Wireless N USB 2.0 Adapter TEW-664UB (Black)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001P9XHHS)

dont know if it fits with raspberry. but the chances are quite good i think.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought [this one from KONIG](http://www.konigelectronic.com/en_us/computer/networking/55917305), and I purchased it via a "[Configure your Raspberry Pi](http://www.gadgetpark.nl/Raspberry-Pi-Model-B)" web-app.

Works perfectly!